# Firebase Function - device token empty

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need help, I've been searching for solutions all day but I can't fix my issue, the code below won't read the device tokens.

Below contains my db structure. I manage to receive the log: **'We have a new News for you.'** When I added a new post but I received the log "**There are no notification tokens to send to.**" Which means it cannot detect the device tokens even though there is already ones. What am I doing wrong?

```js
{

  "Newsv2" : {
"All" : {

  "-Ktr7ZkuChCjsUIMb_4f" : {
    "title" : "",
    "type" : "",
  }
},

 "Usersv2" : {

"h0RzzpdO7nZVLpAR4fi7xRWUqsT2" : {
  "device_token" : "",
  "name" : "",
  "user_no" : ""
}
  },
  
  }



/--News
    --All
       --name
       --desc

/--Usersv2
    --{userID}
      --device_token


exports.sendNotif = functions.database.ref('/Newsv2/All/{newsID}').onWrite(event => {
  const newsID = event.params.newsID;
  const userID = event.params.userID;

  if (!event.data.val()) {
    return console.log('News! ', newsID);
  }
  console.log('We have a new News for you!',newsID);

  // Get the list of device notification tokens.
  const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref(`/Usersv2/${userid}/device_token`).once('value');

  return Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise]).then(results => {
    const tokensSnapshot = results[0];
    //const follower = results[1];

    // Check if there are any device tokens.
    if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
      return console.log('There are no notification tokens to send to.');
    }
    console.log('There are', tokensSnapshot.numChildren(), 'tokens to send notifications to.');
    //console.log('Fetched follower profile', follower);

    // Notification details.
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'Test Message',
        body: '',
        icon: ''
      }
    };

    // Listing all tokens.
    const tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());

    // Send notifications to all tokens.
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(response => {
      // For each message check if there was an error.
      const tokensToRemove = [];
      response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
        const error = result.error;
        if (error) {
          console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
          // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
          if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
              error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
            tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
          }
        }
      });
      return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Post the code that creates `getDeviceTokensPromise`.  When does it run?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include it in. // Get the list of device notification tokens.
  const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref(`/users/${followedUid}/notificationTokens`).once('value');

Comment: Your database doesn't have the structure or contain the values your code expects.  To get additional help, you'll need to post the exported JSON for the user ID that fails (with placeholders for private data, such as token).  You can do the export from the Firebase console.

Comment: {

  "Newsv2" : {
    "All" : {
      
      "-KtqNC3MTYcJEsAbE3QD" : {
        "title" : 
        "type" : 
      
    },


  },
  "Usersv2" : {
    "h0RzzpdO7nZVLpAR4fi7xRWUqsT2" : {
      "device_token" : 
      "name" : "
      "user_no" : 
    }
  },

}
 is this it?

Comment: Your code expects `device_token` to have one or more children where the key for each child is the token.  That is not in the JSON in your comment. Also, the JSON would be much more readable if it were formatted and included as an edit to your question, instead of as a comment.

Comment: I've edited in the JSON, I made it short because it was very long. How do I retrieve all the device token of each users and send it to all the the tokesn? I'm still so confused on this . Sorry. and const tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val()); the correct way to get all the tokens?

Answer (score 0):

To get the device token I store it in my firebase DB when a user registers or logs in.

```
    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users/");
    //and if the login/register is successful
    mUserDatabase.child("device_token").setValue(deviceToken).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(application.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                                    application.startActivity(intent);
                                                }
                                            });
```

as for my firebase funciton:

```
const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${unique_id}/device_token`).once('value');
```

Comment: Can you checked my edited question again? I forgot to add the function earlier.